# Firebase session login - random log-in and non log-in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Firebase session login - random log-in and non log-in.
https://orz-concepts.firebaseapp.com/

Steps to reproduce:

1. register new user
2. log-in this user
3. refresh page - is logged
   refresh page - is logged
   refresh page - is logged
   refresh page - is not logged in
   refresh page - is logged
   refresh page - is not logged in
   refresh page - is not logged in
   refresh page - is not logged in
   refresh page - is not logged in
   refresh page - is logged
   etc.

I use `onAuthStateChanged` and it just sometimes logs in and sometimes not. I have no influence on it.

I create `window.auth = firebase.auth;`, and get window.auth().currentUser from devTools-Console for check it after some delay but nothing change after delay.
It can not be refreshed otherwise.
I do not know what more I can do.

What is this? Why is this so? How to remedy this?

Comment: Check your connection with localStorage, after some time you clear everything there. 
Also, to not get a huge amount of downvotes, add at least some code with ideas, to show that you tried on your own.

Comment: But I have no idea what I can do about it. I do not even know how to relate to this.

Comment: Why are you attaching it to the window object? You shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: Just to check something. This will not be permanent.